# Scala: Can't access protected constructor?

Tags: java, scala

I tried to create a Node with new Keyword. I did it for both var and val but I keep getting the error.

```
def parseProgram(): Node = {
val node = new Node(NodeType.program)

println(node.toString())
node.addToken(this.`match`(TokenType.program))
node.addNode(this.parseDeclarations())
node.addToken(this.`match`(TokenType.BEGIN))
node.addNode(this.parseStatementSequence())
node.addToken(this.`match`(TokenType.END))
this.`match`(TokenType.EOF)
println("Inside parseProgram before returns")

return node}
```

error: constructor Node in class Node cannot be accessed in class Parser Access to protected constructor Node not permitted because enclosing class Parser is not a subclass of class Node where target is defined

```
val node = new Node(NodeType.program)
           ^
```

Please help!

Comment: whats the definition of Node, NodeType and TokenType?

Comment: Node, NodeType and TokenType are three different scala files. Similarly Parser is also a scala file. I am calling different parameters such as program, BEGIN and END through TokenType file.

Comment: sorry, cant help much without knowing the definitions, but based on the Error you pasted, can you try: class Parser extends Node?